# How to implement a multiple model search in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am to build an application that has multiple models - related and unrelated. I also have to implement a search field that searches all the specified fields of all these models.

```
User:
    name, education, xxx,

UnrelatedDocument:
    title, xxx,

UserDocument:
    User(F), title, xxx,
```

Of the above three models `UnrelatedDocument` is not related with any other model. I was wondering how to implement a common search field for all these models on specific fields?

**Note:** Please don't suggest third-party libraries. I would love to implement it on my own. Just need the insights.

Answer (score 1):

A third party package is likely the way to go as Django's built in [search](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/search/) is quite limited

[Django-Watson](https://github.com/etianen/django-watson) supports search over multiple models as documented [here](https://github.com/etianen/django-watson/wiki#searching-for-models)

[Algolia](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-django#algolia-search-api-client-for-django) is a popular choice for search and it appears you can register multiple models for search as shown in the [quick start](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-django#quick-start)

[Django packages](https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/search/) also includes a listing of popular third party search packages

Comment: No third-party libraries are to be used.

Comment: For a simple solution I would suggest using one query for each model and then handling the results or if you really want to re-invent the wheel read through the open source code of the third party packages for code examples

Comment: Third-party libraries bring so much extra stuff with them which I won't be using. I just want something straight.

Comment: In that case the link included in the answer regarding Django's built in search capabilities should do the trick for you